# How to add a plugin in @ckeditor/ckeditor5-react manually?

Tags: reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor5-react

So, I have a plugin from https://www.pramukhime.com/ which is language plugin.
So, they gave me a zip file containing various files.

Screenshot of file:

[image: plugin files]

I am guessing plugin.js is the main file to import. (Also, it's been minified)

So, I tried the following but getting error

Code:

```
import CKEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react";
import ClassicEditor from "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic";
import Pramukhime from "./../../Assets/pramukhime/plugin.js";

...

        <CKEditor
          editor={ClassicEditor}
          data={questionData}
          config={{
            plugins: [Pramukhime]
          }}
          onChange={(event, editor) => {
            const data = editor.getData();

            handleQuestionEditor(data);

          }}

        />
```

So, how should I add this plugin in my editor?

Thanks

EDIT:
error when added extraPlugins in config

```
config={{extraPlugins:'...'}}
```

[image: error]

Comment: Did you tried following this? - https://js.plus/docs/how-to-install-a-plugin-to-ckeditor

Comment: @KrinaSoni there isn't a folder plugin in ckeditor5-react . Also, those steps are I think for normal ckeditor package not for react integrated ckeditor

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add those files to your `ckeditor/plugins` folder. The readme file will tell you what to name the enclosing folder (if you use a name the plugin doesn't expect, it won't be loaded at all).

After that you'll need to add any dependencies the same way, since CKEditor can't do this automatically. Then you can simply enable the plugin, along with any dependencies by adding one or more `config.extraPlugins = 'plugin-name';` lines to your CKEditor configuration.

Source: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_plugins.html#manual-installation

Comment: I tried your solution but error consoled. see edit of question

Comment: Can you please share the contents of the plugin's README in a pastebin/gist?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the package i think you plugin depend upon another dependency or may be the problem with version compatibility.